# Name of a book about submarine combat

Tags: story-identification, novel, military-sf

But not your standard submarine combat with to steel tubes filled with hundreds of men stalking each other in silence. These submarines were small one man ships akin to fighter aircraft.

The book was from the 80s or very early 90s. I can't remember much about other than the small submarine fighter craft. The paperback edition showed the craft on the cover.

Answer (score 4):

Frederick Pohl's first novel *[Slave Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Ship_(Pohl_novel))*, featured one-person submarines, although along with each human pilot were a small crew of trained animals.  Moreover, that is only the end of the novel.  Before that there are strange recreational drugs and other military activities.

Two covers are here, although there are [many others](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1860&bih=952&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=qb8BW9myMo3CzwK16KGICw&q=slave%20ship%20cover%20pohl&oq=slave%20ship%20cover%20pohl):

[image: Cover image] [image: Cover Image 2]

Free copies of the issues of *Galaxy* that it was published in are available via the Internet Archive:

- [Part 1](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1956-03/Galaxy_1956_03#page/n101/mode/2up)
- [Part 2](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1956-04/Galaxy_1956_04#page/n101/mode/2up)
- [Part 3](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1956-05/Galaxy_1956_05#page/n53/mode/1up)